# Adding style to an object property that is an array and its passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, css-selectors

I have something like that:

```
myObj=[{id:1,name:"name1"},{id:2,name:"name2"},{id:3,name:"name3"}]
```

this is rendered into my component as a prop like that
.
.
.`<MyCustomComponent myProp={myObj}/>`

I tried to map this object and to edit add to the name property for example the .bold() but it renders with the tags like that

```
 <b>name1</b>
```

Is there a way to do that or give like the text color differently just for the name?  (given that MyCustom component is a npm library that I don´t want to edit directly  )

Comment: React will escape all HTML except if you `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
Instead you should let the parent component control how the children are rendered by either passing them as children or pass a render-prop (callback which returns react element)

Comment: So in this case I should only edit directly the react library that I am using?

Comment: of course not. You have to change your component to be able to control how children are rendered. Either you pass them as react `children` or you use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)